# AngularJS dynamic compute text content from another array inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following HTML code and data.

JS:

```
scope.stories=["1","2","3"]
scope.insights=[
{id:"1",name:"something"},
{id:"2",name:"something"},
{id:"3",name:"something"}]



'<div ng-click=""  ng-repeat="story in stories"><h4>{{}}</h4></div>'
```

What I want is to get the name from insights with the id and show it inside "h4" tag. I have many other data stored in stories and insights and that's why I try to do this.

The reason is i have another ng-repeat outside this one.

The real scope.stories is like  [{name:story1,stories:[1,2,3,4]},{name:story2,stories:[1,3]}].
So if I put insight into each of the story, it would be a lot redundant, since I might have a lot more stories and insights.

Anyone can help me with this ? Thanks

Comment: ... is there some reason you cant put insights in the ng-repeat?

Comment: The reason is i have another ng-repeat outside this one. It's like scope.stories = [{name:story1,stories:[1,2,3,4]},{name:story2,stories:[1,3]}]

Comment: So you want the name of the insight where the id matches the story?

Comment: yes get the name by id and put into <h4>{{}}</h4>

Comment: I tried {{insights.filter(function(){});}}.. but it seems like I cannt do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a method in your controller that looks like this:

```
$scope.getInsightFromStory = function(story) {
  var result;

  angular.each($scope.insights, function(insight) {
    if (insight.id === story) {
      result = insight;
    }
  });

  return result;
};
```

Then in your html do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="story in stories" >
  <h4>{{getInsightFromStory(story).name}}</h4>
</div>
```

If you're feeling adventurous, you could use underscore to find your insight pretty easily:

```
$scope.getInsightFromStory = function(story) {
  return _.where($scope.insights, {id: story})[0]
};
```